# cant get the output to show in my outputfile.txt

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void function(){

    char ch;
    int num;
    int n;
    int index = 0;
    std::cout << "enter how manny letter you need to translate first: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    while (index < n){
        std::cin >> ch >> num;
        std::cout << char(ch+num)<<" ";
        index++;
    }
}
int main() {

    std::ofstream outfile;

    outfile.open("D:\\outfile.txt");
    function();

    outfile << function;
    return 0;
}
```

this code asks for the number of letters you want to include ex:3
then you enter the letters with the a number, this number gets added to its ascii value
ex: a 1, out: b,
all of this is done in a void and i want the output "being the new letters" to be in the text file

> the code always prints out 1 instead of the output letters inside the txt file

Comment: `std::cout` is a console output stream, so you write your output to console, not the file. You should pass `outfile` as an argument of your `function()`, then write to `outfile` instead of `std::cout`

Comment: The reason it prints 1 is in this line `outfile << function;`, which is the only line printing to the file. It doesn't work the way you wanted, it takes function address (some number you're probably not interested in) and implicitly converts it to boolean, and in fact function address always is converted to `true` value, which is printed as `1` when you output it.